# Is Mini DisplayPort compatible with the Oculus Rift?

Tags: oculus-rift

Good morning and a Merry Christmas! Today, I received an Oculus Rift as a gift. My computer is compatible with it, but it does not have an HDMI port. I used a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter:

[image: Mini DisplayPort to HDMI converter]

During setup, the software read that the Rift's HDMI was not plugged in. Is miniDisplayPort not compatible with the Oculus Rift?

Comment: According to [**this forum thread**](https://forums.oculus.com/vip/discussion/32148/mini-displayport-hdmi-adaptor-compatible-w-retail-rift), it should work.

Comment: Shameless plug for Area51 proposal: If you find VR type questions interesting consider supporting the [Virtual and Augmented Reality proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102228/virtual-and-augmented-reality?referrer=9mZ23XAfTQDHnqg3wxD2og2) currently on Area51.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this adapter should work. ( Needs to be 4k )
[https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B00K0UDJFI/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K0UDJFI)